# Select DBpedia resource with at least N occurrences of seleted word in abstract?

Tags: rdf, sparql, dbpedia

I have this request that results some DBpedia resources and their abstracts.  How can I filter the results to get just the resources whose abstracts contain at least a certain number of occurrences of a particular word?

```sql
PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl:<http://www.dbpedial.org/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

select distinct ?resource ?url ?resume where {
   ?resource rdfs:label ?Nom.
   ?resource foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?url.
   ?resource dbo:abstract ?resume.
   FILTER langMatches( lang(?Nom), "EN" )
   FILTER langMatches( lang(?resume), "EN" )
   ?Nom <bif:contains> "apple".             
}
```

This is the new request without Bind function:

```
select (strlen(replace(replace(Lcase(?resume), 'Jobs', '_'),'[^_]', '')) as ?nbr )  ?resource ?url 
where {
?resource rdfs:label ?Nom.
   ?resource foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?url.
   ?resource dbo:abstract ?resume.
FILTER langMatches( lang(?Nom), "EN" )    
FILTER langMatches( lang(?resume), "EN" )
?Nom <bif:contains> "Apple".}
GROUP BY ?Nom
Having(?nbr >= 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't be absolutely perfect, but it should work relatively well for what you're trying to accomplish.    You can use **replace** to replace all the instances of the word you want to count with some single character (e.g., '_').  Then you can use **replace** again to replace everything *except* that character with the empty string. Then, you have a string like '______', where the length is the number of times that the word appeared in the string.  For instance, here's a query that counts 'the' in the abstract, and keeps only those where 'the' appears at least five times.

```sql
select ?x ?nThe {
  values ?x { dbr:Horse dbr:Cat dbr:Dog }
  ?x dbo:abstract ?abs 
  filter langMatches(lang(?abs),'en')
  bind(strlen(replace(replace(?abs, '\\sthe\\s', '_'),'[^_]', '')) as ?nThe)
  filter (?nThe >= 5)
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fx%20%3FnThe%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3Fx%20%7B%20dbr%3AHorse%20dbr%3ACat%20dbr%3ADog%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%3Fx%20dbo%3Aabstract%20%3Fabs%20%0D%0A%20%20filter%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Fabs%29%2C%27en%27%29%0D%0A%20%20bind%28strlen%28replace%28replace%28%3Fabs%2C%20%27%5C%5Csthe%5C%5Cs%27%2C%20%27_%27%29%2C%27[%5E_]%27%2C%20%27%27%29%29%20as%20%3FnThe%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aorder%20by%20%3FnThe%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: I give an example, to explain more what i want:
 i want only resources which the abstract contain the word " fruit" at least 10 times.

Comment: @Olfabensaid Ah, I misunderstood the original phrasing of the question, I guess. The same approach can be used, though;  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you, tha's exactly what i want. Just one question: what's the utility of e "\\s" .

Comment: It matches whitespace.  That means that you'll match " the ", but you won't accidentally include, etc., "mathematics", which also includes "the".  Whitespace might not be the best match here, though.  You might want to look into word boundary regular expressions.

Comment: please can you reform the query otherwise, because i try to turn this query in my android project, with Jena Api, but it doesn't support Bind function? Is there another function which replace BInd.

Comment: I think bind should be supported in all implementations, so is wonder whether there was a typo. (Without seeing your code, we can't know, though.) That said, instead of doing 'bind(... as ?x)' you can do it in the select: 'select (... as ?x) ...'.

Comment: I created a new containing all the informations:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33861187/bind-function-in-sparql-with-jena-api?noredirect=1#comment55511172_33861187

Comment: I reword the request otherwise, but it doesn't accept Limt (?nbr>=1). the new request is above.

Comment: @faffou Right, since you're doing `SELECT ... (... AS ?nbr)`, you don't have access to to `?nbr` within the query.  You'll need to use `HAVING`, or use `BIND` inside the query to set ?nbr.

Comment: the same problem with HAVING: Variable 'nbr' is used in the query result set but not assigned. and it's not possible with BIND as i say above (because of the problem of androjena api)

Comment: HAVING goes *outside* the query. E.g., something like `select ... (... as ?nbr) WHERE { ... } HAVING (?nbr ...)`.  Is that how you were using it?  (Again, we can't debug code that we don't have.)

Comment: please any solution with select ... (... as ?nbr) WHERE { ... } HAVING (?nbr ...) ??? it doesn't work!!

Answer (score 0):

it's ok, I find another form for my request:

```
PREFIX rdfs:   <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dbo:     <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
select distinct ?Nom ?resource ?url 
where {
   ?resource rdfs:label ?Nom.
   ?resource foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?url.
   ?resource dbo:abstract ?resume.
FILTER langMatches( lang(?Nom), "EN" )    
FILTER langMatches( lang(?resume), "EN" )
?Nom <bif:contains> "Apple".
FIlTER regex(?resume,"Jobs")}
```

Thinks to all those who have tried to help me