# Bind function in SPARQL with Jena API

Tags: android, sparql, jena

I use jena for android to send a query to DBpedia. This is my query:

```
    protected Vector<List> doInBackground(String... keyword) {
                VecDBpedia=new Vector();
                vecurl= new ArrayList();
                 int i=0;
                 ResultSet results,re = null ;
                 QueryExecution exec = null ;
    try{           
              do{
               if(i!=VectorKeyWords.size())
                 {System.out.println(keyword[i]);
                String sparqlQuery=

                        "PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>\n" +
                            "PREFIX dbo:     <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>\n" +
                            "PREFIX rdfs:   <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> \n" +
                            "prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> \n"+
                            "PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>\n"+


                            "select distinct ?nbr ?Nom ?resource ?url where {\n" +
                            "?resource rdfs:label ?Nom.\n" +
                                "?resource foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?url.\n" +
                                 "?resource dbo:abstract ?resume.\n"+
                                "FILTER  langMatches( lang(?Nom), \"EN\") .\n" +
                                "FILTER langMatches( lang(?resume), \"EN\" )\n"+
                                "?Nom <bif:contains> \"Apple\".\n"+
                                "bind(strlen(replace(replace(Lcase(?resume), \"jobs\", \"_\"),\"[^_]\", \"\")) as ?nbr )\n"+
                                "filter (?nbr >= 1)\n"+
                                "}" ;

            String service=  "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";

            Query qur=QueryFactory.create(sparqlQuery,Syntax.syntaxARQ);
            System.out.print("sparqlQuery"+sparqlQuery);

             exec =QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(service,qur );
             System.out.print("qur"+qur);
              re =exec.execSelect();
              System.out.print("re"+re);

            i++;
            System.out.println(re.hasNext());}  

              } while(re.hasNext()==false && i<VectorKeyWords.size());
          if(i==VectorKeyWords.size())  //si aucun des mot clé ne se trouve dans DBpedia
     { System.out.println("Aucun mot clé ne correspond à une entrée en DBpedia");
     cancel(true);// A vérifier
     finish();}


     results = ResultSetFactory.copyResults( re );
     ResultSetFormatter.out( results );
     while ( results.hasNext() ) {
                ArrayList<String>   listDBpediaResource=new ArrayList();
                QuerySolution node=  results.next();

                RDFNode colonne1=node.get( "Nom" );
                RDFNode colonne2=node.get( "resource" );
                RDFNode colonne3=node.get( "url" );

                // RDFNode s2= results.next().get( "url" );
                 listDBpediaResource.add(colonne2.toString());
                 listDBpediaResource.add(colonne3.toString());
                 listDBpediaResource.add(colonne1.toString());

                 VecDBpedia.add(listDBpediaResource);
                 vecurl.add(colonne3.toString());//creer un vecteur contenant les url de chaque ressource condidat de dbpedia

                }


            }  catch (Exception  e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{exec.close();}

            return VecDBpedia;
        }
         ;
```

this query works at SPARQL endpoint, and also in a java application, but does'nt work in android application.

I get this message while executing the code:

```
W/System.err(8123): com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException: Lexical error at line 13, column 5.  Encountered: "(" (40), after : "bind"
W/System.err(8123):     at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.ParserARQ.perform(ParserARQ.java:95)
W/System.err(8123):at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.ParserARQ.parse(ParserARQ.java:39)
W/System.err(8123):     at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.parse(QueryFactory.java:129)
W/System.err(8123):     at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:72)
W/System.err(8123):     at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:43)
W/System.err(8123):     at com.example.testtvprg.MainActivity$AsyncDBpedia.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:426)
W/System.err(8123):     at com.example.testtvprg.MainActivity$AsyncDBpedia.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
W/System.err(8123):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
W/System.err(8123):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
W/System.err(8123):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
 W/System.err(8123):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
W/System.err(8123):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
W/System.err(8123):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
W/System.err(8123):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I think that it's a problem of jena or arq version, but i don't know how to correct it.
Any one can help me please.
Thanks

Comment: Any response please!!

Comment: The Android port (which is separate from the Apache Jena project) uses an older ARQ.  Maybe BIND is not supported.

Comment: `<bif:contains>` is specific to Virtuoso.

Comment: @AndyS How can i make the query please?

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
QueryExecution queryExecution =
QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(ontology_service, query);
```

try to use :

```
QueryExecution execution = new QueryEngineHTTP(ontology_service, query);
```

i assume you use it cause your code is incomplete at the moment (it only shows your `String query = ...`)

**let me know if that works ;)**

**EDIT :**

maybe try to follow my own query and adapt it to your needs :

```
private String entityQuery(String params) {
        return
                "PREFIX ontology: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>\n" +
                        "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\n" +
                        "PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>\n" +
                        "SELECT DISTINCT ?thumb ?entity ?desc ?label ?pic \n" +
                        " WHERE\n" +
                        " {\n" +
                        "?entity  a ontology:" + category + ";\n" +
                        "ontology:abstract ?desc;\n" +
                        "rdfs:label ?label.\n" +
                        "OPTIONAL{?entity foaf:depiction ?pic;" +
                        "ontology:thumbnail ?thumb}. " +
                        "FILTER(langmatches(lang(?desc),\"en\")" +
                        " && langmatches(lang(?label),\"en\"))\n" +
                        "?desc <bif:contains> \"'" + params + "'\"\n" +
                        "}ORDER BY ?label LIMIT 10000 OFFSET 0";
    }
```

and here is the QueryExecution in my `doinBackground()` asynctask

```
Query query = QueryFactory.create(entityQuery(params[0]));
        QueryExecution execution = new QueryEngineHTTP("http://dbpedia.org/sparql", query);
        try {
            ResultSet results = execution.execSelect();

            while (results.hasNext()) {

                Entity a = new Entity();
                QuerySolution row = results.nextSolution();

                if (row.getResource("pic") != null)
                    a.setDepiction(row.get("pic").toString().replace("http", "https"));
                if (row.getResource("thumb") != null)
                    a.setThumb(row.get("thumb").toString().replace("http", "https"));

                a.setTitle(row.getLiteral("label").getString());

                a.setSummary(row.getLiteral("desc").getString());
                fragmentResults.getEntities().add(a);
            }
            execution.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and i noticied that you removed the bind(... part of your query, so i recommend you to try **`QueryEngineHTTP`** now it should work

i also wonder why youre using **RDFNODE**?

**Edit2**

if you want to filter words that contains also i suggest you to do your query like that :

```
PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl:<http://www.dbpedial.org/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

    select distinct ?resource ?url ?resume where {
       ?resource rdfs:label ?Nom.
       ?resource foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?url.
       ?resource dbo:abstract ?resume.
       FILTER langMatches( lang(?Nom), "EN" )
       FILTER langMatches( lang(?resume), "EN" )
       ?Nom <bif:contains> "'apple'".
       ?resume <bif:contains> "'Jobs'"


    }
```

**edit3**

```
 protected Vector<List> doInBackground(String... keyword) {
                    VecDBpedia=new Vector();
                    vecurl= new ArrayList();
                     int i=0;
                     ResultSet results,re = null ;
                     QueryExecution exec = null ;
        try{           
                  do{
                   if(i!=VectorKeyWords.size())
                     {System.out.println(keyword[i]);
                    String sparqlQuery=
     PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
    PREFIX dbpedia-owl:<http://www.dbpedial.org/>
    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
    PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

        select distinct ?resource ?url ?resume where {
           ?resource rdfs:label ?Nom.
           ?resource foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?url.
           ?resource dbo:abstract ?resume.
           FILTER langMatches( lang(?Nom), "EN" )
           FILTER langMatches( lang(?resume), "EN" )
           ?Nom <bif:contains> "'apple'".
           ?resume <bif:contains> "'Jobs'"


        }

                String service=  "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";

                Query qur=QueryFactory.create(sparqlQuery,Syntax.syntaxARQ);
                System.out.print("sparqlQuery"+sparqlQuery);

                 exec =QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(service,qur );
                 System.out.print("qur"+qur);
                  re =exec.execSelect();
                  System.out.print("re"+re);

                i++;
                System.out.println(re.hasNext());}  

                  } while(re.hasNext()==false && i<VectorKeyWords.size());
              if(i==VectorKeyWords.size())  //si aucun des mot clé ne se trouve dans DBpedia
         { System.out.println("Aucun mot clé ne correspond à une entrée en DBpedia");
         cancel(true);// A vérifier
         finish();}


         results = ResultSetFactory.copyResults( re );
         ResultSetFormatter.out( results );
         while ( results.hasNext() ) {
                    ArrayList<String>   listDBpediaResource=new ArrayList();
                    QuerySolution node=  results.next();

                    RDFNode colonne1=node.get( "Nom" );
                    RDFNode colonne2=node.get( "resource" );
                    RDFNode colonne3=node.get( "url" );

                    int matches = 0;
                    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("Jobs",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(colonne2.toString());
                    while (matcher.find()) matches++;
                Log.d("numMatches","jobs"+"("+matches+")");


                    // RDFNode s2= results.next().get( "url" );
                     listDBpediaResource.add(colonne2.toString());
                     listDBpediaResource.add(colonne3.toString());
                     listDBpediaResource.add(colonne1.toString());




                     VecDBpedia.add(listDBpediaResource);
                     vecurl.add(colonne3.toString());//creer un vecteur contenant les url de chaque ressource condidat de dbpedia

                    }


                }  catch (Exception  e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally{exec.close();}

                return VecDBpedia;
            }
             ;
```

so i added this to your asynctask :

```
int matches = 0;
                        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("Jobs", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(colonne2.toString());
                        while (matcher.find()) matches++;
                    Log.d("numMatches","jobs"+"("+matches+")");
```

regarding the logger, it will return you the number of matches of "Jobs into the colonne2 string... can you test it please? also check at your logcat to know if the number is correct...
with this technique you can easy filter example like that

```
int matches = 0;
                    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("Jobs",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(colonne2.toString());
                    while (matcher.find()) matches++;
                Log.d("numMatches","jobs"+"("+matches+")");


                    // RDFNode s2= results.next().get( "url" );
                  if(matches > 1)
                     {
                     listDBpediaResource.add(colonne2.toString());
                     listDBpediaResource.add(colonne3.toString());
                     listDBpediaResource.add(colonne1.toString());
                     }
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I will update my code and make all function.

Comment: this is my problem: BIND function. it doesn't work while executing in android code. Whereas it works well in other queries without BIND.

Comment: what you trying to do with bind?

Comment: I want to calculate the number of the word "Jobs", in all resources that its label contain the word "apple", and then filtering only resources having most then one word "jobs". i had the help to this query on this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33811501/select-dbpedia-resource-with-at-least-n-occurrences-of-seleted-word-in-abstract/33811889?noredirect=1#comment55511844_33811889

Comment: you mean in abstract?

Comment: i am not expert in SPARQL, if i can replace bind function, please help me.

Comment: sorry, yes in abstract.

Comment: if i find a solution to do this ill let you know ;) but you want 1 match or more than 1 match with "jobs"?

Comment: Why can't you use QueryEngineHttp instead of QueryExecutionFactory? this would avoid the parsing of JENA and just send it to the remote endpoint.

Comment: Yes, that's what's I was thinking. This would avoid the reformulation of the query, if it already works directly on the endpoint.

Comment: @AKSW , i have the same problem with QueryEngineHttp

Comment: QueryEngineHTTP back then may, or may not, allow the string to be used directly.  The androjena departure point was some time ago.  Check their documentation or code. A complete different appraoch is to to make the HTTP call yourself, making the query request according to the protocol spec, get the input stream return and have androjena parse that.

Comment: @AndyS can you please give me the jar files that  you use in your example.

Comment: @AndyS can you please give me an example of the last methode you describe.

Comment: Use QueryEngineHTTP(String serviceURI, String queryString) to avoid local query parsing.  Note: you can look at the source code for androjena easily: https://github.com/lencinhaus/androjena/

Answer (score 0):

Thinks to all those wanted to help me. I finally decide to change the function BIND of the query, because it doesn't work with QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService neither with QueryEngineHttp. It's a temporary solution, because may be i would need to other functions that will have the same problem. If anyone  knows a solution , i will be grateful.